# using xquery to count employees in department (same lvl tag)

Tags: xquery, flwor

I have a xml file like this:

```
<employees>
    <emp_num>
        <department>1</department>
        <salary>1000</salary>
    </emp_mum>
    <emp_num>
        <department>1</department>
        <salary>2000</salary>
    </emp_mum>
</employees>
```

I want to know the number of employees per department ordered by the average salary of the department.

My main problem to do this is that "department" and "salary" are at the same level and I don't know how to use FLWOR in this situation.

Comment: At least show us your attempt to group `emp_num` by `department` or in what way your knowledge of FLOWR doesn't suffice, it is not clear where you are struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
for $emp in //emp_num
group by $d := $emp/department
order by avg($emp/salary)
return count($emp)
```

Comment: It was so easy that I did not see it and tried to do much more complicated things

Comment: I'm relieved, since it was untested ;-)